# Visual Studio 2010 Dev Server Stopped Serving Style Sheets When Debugging ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

About an hour ago my VS2010 stopped serving style sheets for both web projects in a solution. A hard refresh (Ctrl F5) brings the sheets back, but when I navigate to the next page, I have no style sheet again.

I've restarted my machine, cleaned and rebuilt the solution, stopped and started the dev server(s) several times, and hit the F5 key extra specially hard several times, none of which seem to have helped. I have not changed any settings, so presume this is some sort of bug.

Is this common, anyone else had to fix this or have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `Net` tab in FireBug or the Network tab in Google Chrome Developer Tools? It will indicate which files are sent with the request.

Comment: +1, thanks yeah that's just occurred to me. Why it didn't sooner!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This was caused a gzip http module in the application. Simple fix, I'll leave the question here for myself or anyone else that runs into the same issue.

Found the problem using Fiddler http debugger.